# Using pointers as data for functions

Tags: c++, pointers

Ok so we have a function called `incr` which simply increases a number by 1,and then returns the new value,but take pointers as arguments:

```
int incr(int *arg) 
{ 
    *arg++; 
    return *arg;
}
```

So if we write the following :

```
int main()
   {
    int i = 1, j = 0;
    cout <<  j << endl;
    int* p_i = &i;
    j = incr(p_i); // changes both i and j
    cout << i << ", " << j << endl; //should print 2, 2 
    return 0;
    }
```

Since we use as an argument a pointer of variable `i`,if something happens to `*p_i` inside the `incr` function,then change would be permanent to `i` when `incr` is finished.Also since we set `j=incr(i)` and we dont return `p_i` itself, but its content(which is now 2-value of `i`),`j` should now be 2.But for some reason, the result is this:

```
1, -858993460
```

And i simply dont understand why.Maybe i have understood something wrong in this hole pointers/function calls thing.Any help would be appriciated

Comment: Soooo many answers...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) issue.

`operator++` has more priority than `operator*`, therefore you're **incrementing the address**, **then** dereferencing it.

```
(*arg)++;
```

Will fix your issue.

Comment: thanks a lot,answer is very clear, will accept as soon as its available!!

Answer (score 6):

`*arg++;` will be parsed as `*(arg++);` because of higher precedence of operator `++` over dereference operator `*`. It will increment the pointer `arg` and then fetch the value of the incremented pointer, which is uninitialized. In this case your program may invoke undefined behavior.
You need to change it to `(*arg)++;`.

Comment: thanks a lot,answer is very clear, will accept as soon as its available!!

Answer (score 2):

Postfix `++` has higher precedence than unary `*`, so `*arg++` is being *parsed* as `*(arg++)` - instead of incrementing the result of `*arg`, you're dereferencing the result of `arg++`, which is not what you want here.

You'll need to explicitly group the `*` operator with `arg` using parentheses:  `(*arg)++`.

Comment: thanks a lot,answer is very clear, will accept as soon as its available!!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that within the functopn there is used less suitable operator (post-increment).:)

Instead of

```
*arg++;
```

that has no the behavior you are expecting it would be better to write

```
++*arg;
```

This expression is more consistent with the statement logic.

As for this expression

```
*arg++;
```

then the function with it is equivalent to the following function definition

```
int incr(int *arg) 
{
    int tmp = *arg;

    arg++;

    return *arg;
}
```

and has undefined behavior because the result pointer in the variable `arg` points outside the original object.

Answer (score 1):

Try this
    int incr(int *arg) 
    { 
        (*arg) += 1;
        return *arg;
    }

Or
 maybe

Answer (score 1):

Since [`++` has precedence over `*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `*arg++` is equivalent to `*(arg++)` and increment the pointer before reading the memory pointed to unknown memory, which is *undefined behaviour*.

You can fix your `incr` function with parenthesis:

```
int incr(int *arg) 
{ 
    (*arg)++;
    return *args;
}
```

or use a prefix notation:

```
int incr(int *arg) 
{ 
    return ++*arg; 
}
```